# how allow only pdf,xlsx files to upload in java upload api running behind nginx server?

Tags: java, linux, api, ubuntu, nginx

I've following java api endpoint, I'm trying to hit with postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://demo-api.xxx.in/bsa/external/uploadbankstatement' \
--header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
--form 'file=@"/home/anuj/Downloads/Config (1).json"' \
--form 'data="{
 \"entityName\": \"Allied Agencies\",
 \"pan\": \"ABCDE1234F\",
 \"monthlyDrawingPowerLimit\": [
 {
 \"month\": \"06\",
 \"year\": \"2021\",
 \"amount\": \"20000\"
 }
 ],
 \"sanctionLimit\": \"245000\",
 \"entityType\": \"company\",
 \"bankCode\": \"FI00002\",
 \"accountType\": \"over_draft\",
 \"accountNumber\": \"123456789\",
 \"relatedPartyKeywords\": \"ARMAN FINANCIAL SERVICES LIMITED\",
 \"userapplicationid\": \"Shub01\",
 \"filePassword\": {
 \"OpTransactionHistory20-10-2021 (4) (1).pdf\": \"1234\"
 }
}"'
```

I've following nginx server location  block where the java backend api running:

```
location /bsa/external/uploadbankstatement{
    
        # Pass the request to the upstream server
     
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;  
  location /bsa/external/uploadbankstatement/ {
    upload_pass /bsa/external/uploadbankstatement;
       if ($request_filename !~* ^.*\.pdf$) {
                return 403;
            }
       # proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        client_body_temp_path /temp;
        client_body_in_file_only on;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
      
    }
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

I need to configure above location block such that only pdf are allowed to be uploaded, but in above configuration, it is not blocking files other than pdf, all files are accepted in above.
Please help me out.